# Apex Class Fail: Trig_Contact: execution of AfterInsert caused by: System.ListException: List index out of bounds: 0

Tags: apex, unit-test

I have an old Test that is causing some of my new Triggers to fail on deployment and would love any help I can get!

It's worth nothing that the fundraiser object is now a child of campaigns, so the campaign is required.

Here is the Apex Class that is failing:

```
@isTest
private class TEST_PmtCompletedCreateOppty {
    static testMethod void doTest() {

       test.startTest();

         //create test objects
         Campaign cm1 = new Campaign();
         cm1.name='Not Sorted';
         cm1.IsActive=true;
         Campaign cm2 = new Campaign();
         cm2.name='Wednesday WIN';
         cm2.IsActive=true;
         Campaign cm3 = new Campaign();
         cm3.name='Made With Pencils Campaign';
         cm3.IsActive=true;
         Campaign camp = new Campaign();
         camp.Name = 'Holiday Welcome';
         insert camp;

         Fundraiser__c f1 = new Fundraiser__c();
         f1.name='My Fundraiser';
         f1.Marketing_Campaign__c='';
         f1.Campaign__c = camp.Id;
         insert f1;

         Contact c1 = new Contact();
         Contact c2 = new Contact();
         c1.FirstName = 'Bill';
         c1.LastName = 'Smith';
         c2.FirstName = 'Jill';
         c2.LastName = 'Smith';
         insert c1;
         insert c2;

         pymt__Payment_Profile__c r1 = new pymt__Payment_Profile__c();
         r1.name='Foo';
         r1.pymt__Amount__c=19.69;
         r1.pymt__Contact__c=c1.Id;
         r1.pymt__Frequency__c=1;
         r1.pymt__Subscription_Start_Date__c=System.Today();
         r1.pymt__Period__c='Month';
         r1.pymt__Currency_ISO_Code__c='USD';
         r1.pymt__Invoice_Number__c=f1.Id + '|1'; 
         insert r1;

         pymt__PaymentX__c p1 = new pymt__PaymentX__c();
         pymt__PaymentX__c p2 = new pymt__PaymentX__c();
         pymt__PaymentX__c p3 = new pymt__PaymentX__c();
         p1.pymt__Amount__c=12.56;
         p2.pymt__Amount__c=10.23;
         p3.pymt__Amount__c=19.69;        
         p1.pymt__Contact__c=c1.Id;
         p2.pymt__Contact__c=c2.Id;
         p3.pymt__Contact__c=c1.Id;
         p3.pymt__Payment_Processor__c='Paypal';                     
         p1.pymt__Status__c='Completed';
         p2.pymt__Status__c='Completed';
         p3.pymt__Status__c='Completed';         
         p1.pymt__Transaction_Type__c='Payment';
         p2.pymt__Transaction_Type__c='Payment';
         p3.pymt__Transaction_Type__c='Payment';         
         p1.pymt__Date__c=System.Today(); 
         p2.pymt__Date__c=System.Today();
         p3.pymt__Date__c=System.Today();
         p1.pymt__Merchant_Custom_Data__c=f1.Id + '|1'; 
         p2.pymt__Merchant_Custom_Data__c=f1.Id + '|0';
         p3.pymt__Payment_Profile__c=r1.Id;                       
         insert p1;
         insert p2;
         insert p3;

         update p1;
         update p2;
         update p3;

        // Query the database for the newly inserted records.
        Opportunity o1 = [SELECT id,name,amount,campaignId FROM Opportunity WHERE amount = :12.56 LIMIT 1];
        Opportunity o2 = [SELECT id,name,amount,campaignId FROM Opportunity WHERE amount = :10.23 LIMIT 1];
        Opportunity o3 = [SELECT id,name,amount,campaignId FROM Opportunity WHERE amount = :19.69 LIMIT 1];

        //is it kosher?
        //System.assertEquals(c1.FirstName + ' ' + c1.LastName + ' Donation',o1.name);
        //System.assertEquals(c2.FirstName + ' ' + c2.LastName + ' Donation',o2.name);
        System.assertEquals(12.56,o1.amount);
        System.assertEquals(10.23,o2.amount);
        System.assertEquals(19.69,o3.amount);
        System.assertEquals(cm1.Id,o1.campaignId);
        System.assertEquals(cm1.Id,o2.campaignId);

      test.stopTest(); 

    }
}
```

Here is the Trigger:

```
trigger OnPmtCompletedCreateOppty on pymt__PaymentX__c (before insert, before update, after update) {
        for (pymt__PaymentX__c p : Trigger.new) {
            if ((p.pymt__Status__c == 'Completed' || p.pymt__Status__c == 'Charged') && p.pymt__Opportunity__c==null) {                               
                String contactId = p.pymt__Contact__c;
                List<Contact> contacts = [select id, name, account.id, account.name from Contact where id =:contactId];
                if (contacts.size()==0) { return; }
                Contact c = contacts[0];
                List<Account> accounts= [select id, name from Account where id =:c.account.id];
                if (accounts.size()==0) { return; }
                Account a = accounts[0];            
                if (p.pymt__Transaction_Type__c == 'Payment') {
                    // Set up opportunity
                    Opportunity o = new Opportunity();
                    o.AccountId= a.id;
                    //o.npe01__Contact_Id_for_Role__c = contactId;                    
                    o.Name = c.name + ' Donation';
                    o.Probability = 100;åç
                    o.StageName = 'Posted';
                    o.CloseDate = p.pymt__Date__c;
                    o.Amount= p.pymt__Amount__c;
                    List<Campaign> campaigns = [select id from Campaign where name =:'Not Sorted' LIMIT 1];
                    if (campaigns.size()>0) {
                       o.CampaignId = campaigns[0].id;
                    }
                    insert o;
                    p.pymt__Opportunity__c=o.id;
                    Boolean hasOcr = false;
                    List<OpportunityContactRole> ocrs= [select id from OpportunityContactRole where OpportunityId=:'o.id' AND ContactId=:'o.id' LIMIT 2];
                    if (ocrs.size()>0) {
                        hasOcr = true;
                    }
                    if (!hasOcr) {                 
                        OpportunityContactRole ocr = new OpportunityContactRole();
                        ocr.isPrimary=true;
                        ocr.OpportunityId = o.id;
                        ocr.ContactId = c.id;
                        ocr.Role = 'Donor';
                        insert ocr;
                    }
                }
                //else if (p.pymt__Transaction_Type__c == 'Refund') {
                    //delete one existing opportunity that matches
                //}
            } 
    }
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Would be very helpful it you could post the line number and indicate where that line is in the code....At first glance I do not see in your trigger where that error would occur as you are checking indexes - Oh, I see - you `DID NOT` paste the trigger that was producing the error..

Comment: The error is happening in `Trig_Contact` so that is the code you need to provide

Comment: @Eric Oh I'm sorry, you're right! Class.TEST_PmtCompletedCreateOppty.doTest: line 33, column 1

Comment: @BarCotter  This is the code for Trig_Contact: `trigger Trig_Contact on Contact (after insert, after update) {
et4ae5.triggerUtility.automate('Contact');
}`

Comment: @BarCotter I'm very new to this, but the `Trig_Contact` trigger is what ExactTarget provided in order for me to set up triggered emails

Comment: Ok, if you were given this what would be your next question? Maybe "What is in the et4ae5.triggerutility.automate class? (But I am guessing this is a managed package so you would have to reach out to your vendor.) I would assume that the contacts you are creating do not meet some criteria in the managed utility and that code is not checking to see if a list is empty

Comment: @Eric When I try to push Trig_Contact to production (along with a Class) it tells me that the OnPmtCompletedCreateOppty trigger has 0% code coverage. Yet the Class for that is what I pasted above. Maybe the Class is not testing the entire Trigger? (again apologies if I sound like a buffoon, I am a beginner!)

Comment: If the test fails when it inserts a contact it never makes it to the other code that causes the other trigger to fire , hence 0% coverage on that trigger

Comment: @Eric thanks, I called the vendor and they think it might be their issue so they're looking into it - i appreciate all your help!

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you SQL query the opportunities by their connection to the created contacts/payments ID's? Selecting them by amount is definitely "not kosher" since there could be other opportunities with the same amount